# Unable to run PDFKIT command in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, pdfkit

I am following [this](http://blog.10to1.be/rails/2010/08/18/pdfkit-and-ruby-on-rails/) tutorial, but in Windows. When I run:

```
pdfkit --install-wkhtmltopdf
```

from my application directory, the `pdfkit` command is not recognized:

```
'pdfkit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

`gem list` shows that I do have the `pdfkit` gem installed:

```
pdfkit (0.5.0)
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by run a gem? You can't run a gem per-se, but you might be able to run binaries that the gem installs.

Comment: I'm trying to translate the instructions here: http://blog.10to1.be/rails/2010/08/18/pdfkit-and-ruby-on-rails/ to Windows.

Comment: there is a windows installer for wkhtmltopdf... as i've already explained to you [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163315/rails-how-to-print-models-details-to-a4-pdf-page/5163993#5163993) it works, i've tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't run the command is because the gem has changed since August 2010, when the blog post you mention was written. If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit) you'll see that there are no binaries at all, so running a pdfkit install command will not work. To install wkhtmltopdf (which is what that command is attempting to do) I would recommend following the instructions [here](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF). For full instructions on using the new pdfkit gem I would follow [these instructions](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: [Remove automated installer commit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/commit/add90fd163a99b5767a5e0315d6b53ef48beccdf)