# Rails 3 + PDFKit Problem: Permission denied (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I would like to use [PDFKit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit) in my Rails 3 application **on Windows**.

I installed `wkhtmltopdf` and the `pdfkit` gem.

Here is the code that I use to create the PDF:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def create_pdf_invoice
    kit = PDFKit.new("<h1>Hello</h1><p>This is PDF!!!</p>", :page_size => "A4")
    file = kit.to_file("my_first_pdf")   # Error issued here!!
    ...
  end
end
```

I got the following error:

```
Errno::EACCES in JobsController#create_pdf_invoice

Permission denied - "c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf" "--page-size" "A4" 
                    "--margin-top" "0.75in" "--margin-right" "0.75in" 
                    "--margin-bottom" "0.75in" "--margin-left" "0.75in" 
                    "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--quiet" "-" "my_first_pdf"
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will get that error if you point to a **folder** and not the actual **file** (.exe)

I got PDFkit to run on windows like this:

```
  PDFKit.configure do |config|
    config.wkhtmltopdf = 'C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
  end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. I wonder if you could help me also with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177074/rails-3-pdfkit-how-to-print-a-view-to-pdf. Many thanks!